# UEFI - Windows 10 /Ubuntu 20 Dual Boot on a separate SSD starts in grub prompt - hd1/sdb not recognized

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows, dual-boot, uefi

So, I read a lot of posts and answers about this, but maybe my case is... too specific?

I have a not-so-old Hp notebook (2-3 years old). I removed the DVD drive and added a Kingston SSD via caddy. The Notebook has the InsydeH20 Bios.

So, I created a Live Ubuntu pendrive with Rufus in GPT mode. Installed ubuntu from scratch in the new SSD... and the thing boots in grub prompt. No sign of the new SSD there.

If you boot the live pendrive, you can see the disk and partitions in Gparted, play with them, mount them, etc. But in grub prompt you will always see hd0 (which has the windows installation and the UEFI things), and if I left the pendrive connected, hd2. You can ls both of them from grub and see the files.

hd1 (which is always sdb in the live ubuntu pendrive) only appears as hd1, no partitions -ie. hd1,gpt1-. If you "ls" it, you can see the message "No know filesystem detected". Also, every time you run ls, you will see the next message: "error: failure reading sector 0x0 from 'hd1'

I cannot use configfile or set root to add the kernel because, I assume, grub does not like my SSD.

I tried a bunch of things, but I might be a little lost at this point.

-Used boot repair from the live pendrive -Installed grub in many different ways (right now I installed grub efi) -The UEFI secure boot is disabled from the BIOS. -The fastboot is disabled from windows. -The BIOS is NOT in legacy mode, but I tried every possible combination, just in case (legacy mode, which left Windows 10 "unbootable". Is working again now) -Used MBR/UEFI instead of GPT (Windows is UEFI/GPT, checked it from Windows itself)

Any tip or advice, I'll try it :)

Comment: If Windows is UEFI, only use gpt and UEFI. Turning on Legacy or using MBR just adds complications that often have to be undone. Did you update SSD firmware? Many, even new SSD need firmware update and even when both UEFI & Windows see SSD. Some have issues booting from a drive in a DVD caddy slot. While DVDs were bootable, some systems will not boot from drive in caddy. Those users install grub to Windows ESP (which is normal) and some otheres have had to also add a /boot into Windows drive, so system boots totally from it. Then / (root) & /home on SSD.

Comment: I followed your suggestion and downloaded the Kingston utility in Windows. It detects the SSD but is already updated to the latest firmware. 
Also, would you give me some more details about putting /boot in the windows drive?
I'll try installing grub in Windows meanwhile

Comment: First try standard UEFI install of Ubuntu (assuming Windows is UEFI). Not sure with Ubiquity installer what it will do in your case. It wants to install grub to first drive's ESP. If that works or a repair to make sure grub is in the internal drive's ESP, then we do not need /boot. If not then during install you have to create /boot on internal drive & / & /home on SSD. I prefer not to have separate /boot on standard desktops installs. Its just another partition to manage. But in your case it may be required.